# TypeScript type for Ref as argument in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem defining type in typescript for ref.

I have `questionsRef` which is a list of refs.

```
  const questionsRef = useRef<Array<HTMLDivElement | null>>([]);
```

I want to pass that `questionsRef` to the utility function, but Typescript requires the correct type of arguments.

How to define questiosnRef: Type here?

```
const focusNextQuestion = (questionsRef: any, nextQuestion: any) => {
  if (questionsRef.current) {
   // some code
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
React.useRef<Array<React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>>>();
```

Comment: Hey @Ekkoko I need defining someting similar to that inside of utility function: 

const focusNextQuestion = (questionsRef: HERE NEED TO DEINE SAME REF, nextQuestion: any)

Comment: If I understood correctly the type of the questionsRef should be `React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>`